# Terse error message with MSVC8: is there any way to be more explicit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have

```
Baz<Foo, Bar> blah_blah(Foo const& f, Bar const& b)
{ return Baz<Foo, Bar>(f, b); }
```

and I get this error:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'Baz<Foo, Bar> blah_blah(Foo, Bar)'
with the following template arguments:
'ConcreteFoo'
'ConcreteBar'
```

which is definitely useless and will likely take me a lot of time investigating the issue (templates involved are quite hairy, and `ConcreteFoo` and `ConcreteBar` are themselves hairy templates).

I'd like to know what types/members objects/member functions are missing from `ConcreteFoo` and `ConcreteBar` which prevent instantiation of the `Baz` template.

Is there a way to work around this idiotic error reporting from Visual C++ 2005 ?

**EDIT** (relevant): Baz, ConcreteFoo and ConcreteBar are like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U, bool = f(T, U), int = g(T, U), etc>
struct Baz
{ ... }
```

and there are quite a few partial specializations. I know which one is taken from the compiler message. Also, the functions f and g are ugly ugly meta programming stuff, and I believe my problem comes from there: there is one of f or g which does not yield the right result. There must be some type / static member missing from either ConcreteFoo or ConcreteBar, and I don't know which one.

Also, it is difficult for me to just grab the relevant parts of the project, and write a side project for testing, I'd like something more "inline".

Comment: why don't you post the full error message as it was?

Comment: This would surely violate my NDA. The error message is just the one I posted, albeit with different names.

Comment: When the compiler is not helping, I try to isolate the problem. For exmaple I would try to: make the function return void and recompile (so as to empty the function of implementation); try with other parameters types, like int, etc...

Comment: Write a side project, perhaps a test, with ConcreteFoo and ConcreteBar as the class names and if you get the same compiler error we will have something to look at to tell you what you are doing wrong,.

Comment: Relevant structs like `Baz` don't appear to be very valid?

Answer (score 0):

ConcreteFoo and ConcreteBar are templates or classes? And so is it a specialization or partial-specialization you are trying?

It's difficult to tell when we can't see a full failing example.

By the way have you tried your code on another compiler like comeau tryitout, before you blame the compiler?

Comment: On a large codebase, it is not easy to port to compile on another compiler. There are too many dependencies and you would only waste time doing that. And when he says NDA, it would mean he is talking about code at his workplace. You will have to do jail time if you start posting work code on forums.

Comment: It is a full specialization. ConcreteBar and ConcreteFoo are fully specialized at the point the compiler is whining. Actually, MSVC doesn't implement two pass lookup, so ConcreteBar and ConcreteFoo are not dependant.